# PHP regex problems with greediness

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove all html that looks like this:

```
<p><font face="Arial" size="2"><a href="#top">Back to the top</a></font></p>
```

The fonts and sizes vary, and possibly some other stuff also.

Just to make sure, I'm using the following regex:

```
/<p.*?><font.*?><a href=.*?>Back.*?<\/a><\/font><\/p>/is
```

However, it matches the complete text string I am searching, such as:

```
<p>However, if this is our reaction, we will indeed be weak in our weaknesses. For the strength of Christ does not come to rest upon us in the midst of discontent and rebellion.</p> <p>Seeing the great design of the Lord in affliction, let us rather take pleasure in our afflictions. Let us glory, that is boast, in them, and in wisdom let us then turn to Jesus Christ our Savior to receive His great strength.</p> <p>Then in our weakness we will be indeed very strong!</p> <p><font face="Arial" size="2"><a href="#top">Back to the top</a></font></p> <hr>
```

What am I doing wrong?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change dots to [^>]

```
/<p[^>]*?><font[^>]*?><a href=[^>]*?>Back[^>]*?<\/a><\/font><\/p>/is
```